# You walked all over me

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, story

> You walked all over me and I felt like I was torn in two. You drove me
> crazy. Yet, you cared for me like I was yours.
>
> You dumped my tea out and I felt meaningless. I had to
> rearrange my life for I’d forgotten who I was since you walked all over me.

Remind me of my identity.

Hint:

> Added tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> A **carpet**

> You walked all over me

> You walk on a carpet

> and I felt like I was torn in two.

> Carpet can be split into **car** and **pet**

> You drove me crazy.

> You can drive a **car**

> Yet, you cared for me like I was yours.

> And you would care for your **pet**

> You dumped my tea out and I felt meaningless.

> Carpet without the tea (T) is **carpe**, which most people will recognise as half of the Latin phrase "carpe diem" (sieze the day), but isn't a word in English.

> I had to rearrange my life for I’d forgotten who I was since you walked all over me.

> If I rearrange (anagram) carpe, I can get **pacer** or **caper**, which are both ways one could move about on the carpet.

Comment: That’s just about right! The last clue I had in mind “recap” as well.